# Update Release Description in Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-releases

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps with some approvers. I want to be able to send the approvers some information in the email they receive asking for approval. I could not find a way to customize the email they receive, but I was wondering if it is possible to update the release description that shows up here?
[image]

This needs to be done dynamically. So, it will need to be done through something like an API request or even a Python script within the release itself.

I have already tried using this API,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

However, I have not been able to get it to work. I get several different kinds of errors. Therefore, if this is the way to go, please include an example of how the API is to be called (what parameters need to be passed in the body).

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56022395/14322227) answering your question?

Comment: Hi @Minura, since this ticket is closed, I post the PowerShell script to invoke the REST API to update your release description in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022066/how-to-set-the-description-of-an-azure-devops-release-via-script/73443179#73443179).